# Can't get the Microsoft Translator API Dictionary Lookup to work

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I suscribed for the free Azure trial to use the Dictionary Lookup feature and got this endpoint and (redacted) API key :

> Grab your keys and endpoint
>
> key1
>
> 084***13
>
> Endpoint
>
> https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/
>
> Every call to Cognitive Services requires the subscription key above. This key needs to be either passed through a query string parameter or specified in the request header. To manage your keys, use the Keys option from the left menu

Then on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/Translator/reference/v3-0-dictionary-lookup) I find a simple example, where it seems I just have to substitute the key:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/dictionary/lookup?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=es" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <client-secret>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "[{'Text':'fly'}]"
```

I test it in my command line, replacing the key, but no success :

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/dictionary/lookup?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=es" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 084***13" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "[{'Text':'fly'}]
```

> {"error":{"code":401000,"message":"The request is not authorized because credentials are missing or invalid."}}

I try to change the endpoint, but no success either :

```
curl -X POST "https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/dictionary/lookup?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=es" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 084***13" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "[{'Text':'fly'}]
```

> {"error":{"code":"404","message": "Resource not found"}}

I assume I'm missing something obvious but the doc isn't exactly newb friendly. What should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a region!

It depends on which resource you subscribed for, because there are 2 options, the [Translator Text API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/) and [Cognitive Services multi-service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/) API

I can see you went with `Cognitive Services multi-service` so, in that case you need to add the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region` value which is stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference)

> When you use a multi-service secret key, you must include two
>   authentication headers with your request. The first passes the secret
>   key, the second specifies the region associated with your
>   subscription.
>
> - Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key
> - Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region

I added it below, you just need to replace `<your-key>` and `<your-region>` with your own!

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/dictionary/lookup?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=es" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <your-key>" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region: <your-region>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "[{'Text':'fly'}]"
```